# RXJS6 Upgrade: ErrorObservable has no exported member 'ErrorObservable'

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6

I have upgraded my Angular 5 app to 6.0.1 and RxJs to 6.1.0.

In one of my services, I have the import below:

```
import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
```

However, I now get the following error:

> Module '"...node_modules/rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable"' has no exported member 'ErrorObservable'.

I have search online for how to import this in rxjs6 or if the name

```
ErrorObservable
```

has changed.

I used this as my guide for the upgrade process:

[RxJS 6 Changes - Overview](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)

Does anyone know how to resolve this import?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#observable-classes

Comment: http://take.ms/E6GziU

Answer (score 25):

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
// import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
```

Thank you everyone! The above is the answer with the old line commented out.

Usage:

```
return throwError('some message');
```